# Check if txt file has text ,if so don't write the same text again?

Tags: file, text, duplicates

So right now I'm making a mod in Minecraft where it takes everyones username from a server and adds it to a txt file, it works but the the problem is I don't want to duplicate the names when I use the command again. Nothing has worked so far. How would I check if the txt already contains the username, don't add it again? Thank you. Again, I need it to before writing another name to the list, check the txt file if it already contains the name, if so don't add it.

```
[code]
        for (int i = 0; i < minecraft.thePlayer.sendQueue.playerInfoList.size(); i++) {
            List playerList = minecraft.thePlayer.sendQueue.playerInfoList;
            GuiPlayerInfo playerInfo = (GuiPlayerInfo) playerList.get(i);
            String playerName = StringUtils.stripControlCodes(playerInfo.name);

            try {
                fileWriter = new FileWriter(GameDirectory() + "\\scraped.txt", true);
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(GameDirectory() + "\\scraped.txt"));
                lineNumberReader = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(GameDirectory() + "\\scraped.txt"));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            printWriter = new PrintWriter(fileWriter);

            try {
                fileWriter.write(playerName + "\r\n");
                lineNumberReader.skip(Long.MAX_VALUE);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            printWriter.flush();
        }
        addMessage("Scraped " + lineNumberReader.getLineNumber() + " usernames!");

    }

[/code]
```

I've tried this too but with this it doesn't even write anymore.

[code]

```
List playerList = minecraft.thePlayer.sendQueue.playerInfoList;

for (int i = 0; i < minecraft.thePlayer.sendQueue.playerInfoList.size(); i++) {
    GuiPlayerInfo playerInfo = (GuiPlayerInfo) playerList.get(i);
    String playerName = StringUtils.stripControlCodes(playerInfo.name);

    String lines;

    try {
        if ((lines = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (!lines.contains(playerName)) {
                bufferedWriter.write(playerName);
                bufferedWriter.newLine();
                bufferedWriter.flush();
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

int linenumber = 0;

try {
    while (lineNumberReader.readLine() != null) {
        linenumber++;
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

[/code]

Comment: Is the file too big to read into memory, check if name exists/add it, and then write it back?

Comment: I've been trying for days, I've been using FileReader but with that it wouldn't even write names anymore. Here, like this (might have types I'm writing this pseudo)

String line;
for ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
if (!line.contains(playername)) {
write...
}
}